# How do you use regex to split a string by a unicode character?

Tags: java, regex

I need help using regular expressions. Ihave read the [Java Regex](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) notes, but could not find a way around my problem.

**PROBLEM**:
I have a String that needs to be split at all occurences of the unicode characters \0 , \1 and \2.

**TRIED**:

```
String msg ="foo\0foo\0bar\2foo\1horse"
msg.split("[\1\0\2]");
```

The above works perfectly (not sure if it is the correct use of regex), but

```
String msg ="foo\0foo\0bar\2foo\1horse\1123123\0123123\21"
msg.split("[\1\0\2]");
```

does not work correctly, as it seems the regex is picking up the \1k (with k any integer)
instead of JUST the \0 and \1 and \2.

Any thoughts?

**SOLVED**:
I found that the issue in testing was that I used my own generated String. Using \1 before the numeric values made String automatically include \1k as the character and not \1. When reading from my source, it came in bytes, and thus had the correct \1 encoded. When decoding and re-encoding (manually), I made the error. Working with the raw data solved the problem.

Alternatively I used the unicode \u0001-\u0002 to re-incode, and that worked as well.
Thanks for all the answers. Learnt some about Regex and unicode.

Comment: I don't think `\0` identifies a unicode character. Rather `\uXXXX` where XXXX is a hex number is the way to specify a unicode escape sequence

Comment: This doesn't solve the regex problem, but might I recommend a more standard form of conveying such information, say XML? You'll find these common problems have been solved with production-ready libraries. I think SAX is even included in the JDK these days (I might be wrong though.)

Comment: I would like to use something more standard, however it is not up to me. The content I need to parse is from another source I cannot control.

Comment: Don’t use the Java preprocessor.

Comment: @tchrist: care to share a link explaining why not and how to effectively avoid doing so?

Comment: @tchrist: Yes please, I would also like to know and a link on how to avoid? Thanks

Comment: @maerics, @Vort3x: For regexes, you can use the  `"\\uXXXX"` notation, or still better, the `"\\x{HHHHH}}"` notation from Java 1.7.  The Java preprocessor is broken in a lot of ways. You cannot use an arbitrary `XXXX` with `"\uXXXX"`, and it even peers into comments, which is evil and stupid and wrong. It is also broken because it doesn’t work on all Unicode, only a minority. The best solution is to use UTF-8 and compile with `javac -encoding UTF-8`. However, that still won’t let you do certain things because of The UTF-16 Curse. Try matching `[-]` to see what I mean. Hopeless.

Comment: He’s using octal escapes, guys, whether he knows it or not.  And of course those are Unicode characters, because all characters in Java are Unicode ones.  Well, except those that aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the Unicode character literal form (`\uXXXX`):

```
String msg ="foo\u0000bar\u0001gah\u0002zip\u0001horse\u0001123123\u0000456456\u00021";
String ss[] = msg.split("[\u0000-\u0002]");
// ss = ["foo", "bar", "gah", "zip", "horse", "123123", "456456", "1"];
```

Comment: Try splitting on `[-]` that way.  Go ahead, I dare ya. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
msg.split("[\u0000\u0001\u0002]");
```

according to http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html